# Timthumb possui problemas com exploit de segurança?

Tags: php

Ouvi programadores falarem que não utilizam o Timthumb ("Um pequeno script php para corte, zoom e redimensionamento de imagens da web (jpg, png, gif). Perfeito para uso em blogs e outras aplicações") por problemas de exploit de segurança.

Alguém sabe me recomendar uma outra biblioteca ou script que já tenha utilizado para que eu possa substituir em meu site?

o Timthumb realmente tem esse problema? se sim por que?

Comment: Um dos programadores que falam isso sou eu, né. Se você fizer uma breve pesquisa no Google, vai ver que é verdade [TimThumb WebShot Code Execution Exploit (Zeroday)](http://wptavern.com/wordpress-security-alert-new-zero-day-vulnerability-discovered-in-timthumb-script)

Comment: [GiTHub - Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) O melhor que conheço, facil de usar, agil. e minha opção B: [Easy PHP Tumbnail](http://www.mywebmymail.com/?q=content/easyphpthumbnail-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema geralmente relacionado ao `Timthumb` é o fato de poder abrir urls externas. No caso, abrindo uma url externa, ele poderia abrir um caminho para um script malicioso, por exemplo.

Uma forma de corrigir isso seria configurando o `Timthumb` , alterando o valor da constante `WEBSHOT_ENABLED` para `false`.

Assim:

```
define('WEBSHOT_ENABLED', false)
```

Atualmente uso o `Timthumb`, mas tenho pensando seriamente em alterar seu uso, devido aos relatados erros de segurança e pelo fato também de ser um código aparentemente antigo. Nesse último caso, como os sistemas em que eu trabalho estão todos com o php em versões mais atualizadas, prefiro evitar utilizar bibliotecas com padrões e codificações antigas.

Uma das bibliotecas que podem ser utilizadas opcionalmente é `Gregwar\Image`.